Python duplication after pyinstaller
I'm converting my python script to an exe using pyinstaller --onefile -w script.py.
However, after the conversion I tried to run the script but it duplicates itself multiple times.
I did the same half a year ago, but I updated my version of the code, hence I have to do it again, but whatever I do, it always runs in duplicate.
It could be that it has to do with my subprocess piece of code:
zip_files = [f for f in os.listdir(data_analysis_folder) if f.endswith(".zip")  # file should end with .zip as extension
             and os.path.getsize(os.path.join(data_analysis_folder, f)) > 2048]  # should be bigger than 2kb to convert

zip_files_zipped = len(zip_files)
errors = []
for zip_file in zip_files:
    file_path = os.path.join(data_analysis_folder, zip_file)
    result = subprocess.Popen([program, "x", "-y", "-p" + password_customer, file_path, "-o" + data_analysis_folder],
                             stdout=subprocess.DEVNULL, stderr=subprocess.DEVNULL)
    result.wait()
    # The -y argument in the subprocess run confirms the replacement of the files automatically

    if result.returncode != 0:
        print(f"Error extracting {zip_file}: {result.stderr}")
        errors.append(f'Error extracting {zip_file}: {result.stderr}')
        errors_df = pd.DataFrame(errors)
        errors_df.to_csv(data_analysis_folder + str("/errors_zipping.csv"), index=False, decimal=",")

Does anybody has an idea of why this could happen?
Thanks,

I'm not sure what exactly you mean by "duplicate itself", but you are calling .wait, so at most there are only 2 things running at the same time, your script and whatever program is.

When I'm executing the exe, it's executing the exe 9 times as I can see in my task manager, while it's suppose to run only 1 time.

The issue have been resolved by starting the process with the following code before importing the other modules:
# Import only light weight module first
import multiprocessing

if __name__ == '__main__':
    multiprocessing.freeze_support()
import pandas as pd and other modules

